# MVC5 Can't validate checkbox or even get value

Tags: c#, ajax, razor, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

I use view model for my view (Razor) page and a model to save result in database. In both model and view model I have declared bools for checkboxes.

```
public bool Faza1 { get; set; }
public bool Faza2 { get; set; }
```

In my view I make checkboxes with CheckBoxFor.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Faza1)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Faza2)
```

When I try to submit my form, if checkboxes are unchecked, in model I get bools Faza1 and Faza2 equals false (it is ok), but if I check any of checkboxses again get false value and error in **ModelState.IsValid** in my ActionResult in controller. Does anyone know what's happening?

BTW I use Ajax form for submitting.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Sacuvaj",
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "mreza",
    OnSuccess = "snimljeno"
}))
```

{

**EDIT:**

Here is my ActionResult from controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult Sacuvaj(TViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ... 
    }

    return PartialView("Mreza", KreirajModel());
 }
```

Comment: Show the controller method your are posting back to

Comment: @StephenMuecke I posted it as edit of question

Comment: What you are claiming does not relate to the code shown. Whether they are checked or not would not add a model state error because they are `bool`'s. Are you sure the model state errors relate to the properties `Faza1 ` and `Faza2`? When you submit and then `return PartialView("Mreza", KreirajModel());`, what is `KreirajModel()`? Is it a method and what does it return (or did you mean `new KreirajModel()`) and how does it relate to `TViewModel`?